# Ansible select host based on combination of EC2 tags

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have 2 VPCs, each of which has a VPN instance, whose configuration I would like to share. Both instances have a `class` tag, whose value is now `vpn_dev`, however, they should differ by the `environment` tags - one would have `environment: default`, and the other `environment: london`.

I also have 2 playbooks, one for each VPC. I would like to run my `vpn` role on exactly one of the instances based on the combination of the `class` and `environment` tags, i.e. select the instance that has `class: vpn_dev` **and** `environment: london`. E.g.

```yaml
- name: Deploy developer VPN in AWS
  hosts:
    - tag_class_vpn_dev
    - tag_environment_london
  roles:
    - vpn
```

However, this would of course install the role on all instances that have `class: vpn_dev` (regardless of `environment`), **and** on all instances that have `environment: london` (regardless of `class`).

Is there a way to achieve this? Currently it seems like the only way is to have a **single** tag that **uniquely** identifies an instance.

Comment: What about templated variables like hosts: "{{ VAR1 }}{{ VAR2 }}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lists of hosts in a playbook is an OR operation by default. You can use AND over to host groups with this syntax:

```
- hosts:
    - tag_class_vpn_dev:&tag_environment_london
```

More about host patterns [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#working-with-patterns)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to apply some ansible role to one host for each tag combination, although I would not recommend it, because this approach IMHO is not idempotent.

One of the possible risk with this scenario is that when you re-run this playbook, selected host for some tag combination can be different from previous run, and therefore you will end up with two instances per this unique tag combination group.

My recommended approach would be to use some tag to mark host which is supposed to be used as VPN role target, and then use ansible to apply VPN role only to hosts marked by this tag.